# Can't add permissions for another user for MachineKeys folder

Tags: windows, permissions

I removed all permissions for an administrator for `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA` and I can't add them back. You can see that `Add` button is grayed out. How can I add permissions for another user in this case?

[image]

Comment: You have to use Advanced to change the permissions on the key.  You might have to change the owner, give Administrators the necessary permissions, then change the owner back to whatever it is currently.

Comment: You may possibly need to make a new Admin User ID, log in as the new ID and change permissions that way.